# Serializing a Python Object to XML (Apple .plist)

Tags: python, xml, plist

I need to read and serialize objects from and to XML, Apple's .plist format in particular. What's the most intelligent way to do it in Python? Are there any ready-made solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [plistlib](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/plistlib.html).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on a Mac, you can use PyObjC.

Here is an example of reading from a plist, from [Using Python For System Administration](http://mwpdf.shownets.net:8080/MacIT%20Conference/IT831_nkersten_cadams.pdf), slide 27.

```
from Cocoa import NSDictionary

myfile = "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist"
mydict = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithContentsOfFile_(myfile)

print mydict["LastSuccessfulDate"]

# returns: 2009-08-11 08:38:01 -0600
```

And an example of writing to a plist (that I wrote):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Cocoa import NSDictionary, NSString

myfile = "~/test.plist"
myfile = NSString.stringByExpandingTildeInPath(myfile)

mydict = {"Nice Number" : 47, "Universal Sum" : 42}
mydict["Vector"] = (10, 20, 30)
mydict["Complex"] = [47, "i^2"]
mydict["Truth"] = True

NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary_(mydict).writeToFile_atomically_(myfile, True)
```

When I then run `defaults read ~/test` in bash, I get:

```
{
    Complex =     (
        47,
        "i^2"
    );
    "Nice Number" = 47;
    Truth = 1;
    "Universal Sum" = 42;
    Vector =     (
        10,
        20,
        30
    );
}
```

And the file looks very nice when opened in Property List Editor.app.